# Creating a Bounding box on pgr_Dijkstra to make it faster

Tags: postgis, sql, pgrouting

I have a problem with the Dijkstra algorithm in regards to the query speed.
My current php script for the query is looking like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
            'SELECT id, source, target, ST_Length(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost, ST_LENGTH(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS reverse_cost
            FROM ".TABLE."',
            ".$startEdge['source'].",
            ".$endEdge['target'].",
            directed := true);";
                    
    $query = pg_query($con, $sql);
```

This takes like 10 seconds for just one query. The OSM data on the database is this one: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/baden-wuerttemberg.html
The table has ~700000 records.

At this speed, it is not really usable for me, because I have to make x queries at a time and can not wait for x*10 seconds for getting the results.

The forum has some advice on how the speed can be increased, like these ones:

[Speeding Up pgr_dijkstra using bounding box in PostGis2.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144115/speeding-up-pgr-dijkstra-using-bounding-box-in-postgis2-0?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Why is any pgr_* routing function taking forever based on OSM data in an pgrouting enabled DB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/why-is-any-pgr-routing-function-taking-forever-based-on-osm-data-in-an-pgrouti/69825#69825)

But I am new to the whole spatial/geographical stuff and have problems adopting the advices given.
I do not want to copy blind and also can not do it because most questions are asked on older versions of pgRouter and not on pgRouter 3.0.

I tried to edit my query in regards to the first gis link and it is now looking like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
            'SELECT id, source, target, ST_Length(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost, ST_LENGTH(geom_way::GEOGRAPHY) AS reverse_cost
            FROM ".TABLE."
            WHERE geom_way && ST_Expand((SELECT ST_Collect(geom_way) FROM ".TABLE." WHERE id IN (".$startEdge['source'].", ".$endEdge['target'].")), 0.01)',
            ".$startEdge['source'].",
            ".$endEdge['target'].",
            directed := true);";
```

In the post, it uses on the FROM in the WHERE statement this: ways_vertices_pgr
What is this? Should this be generated somewhere from the ways table? Because with my query it does not give me anything back.

I also have tried this one, but it did not change anything: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194328/167149

Hopefully, someone can help me with this.
If you need more information do not hesitate to ask!

Kind regards
Lars

Comment: How exactly did you create the network topology? If there is no vertice table, check [`pgr_createVerticesTable`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_createVerticesTable.html) to do just that. Make sure its `id` column is indexed, then reference that table in the inner `SELECT` (also using its column names). The idea here is to get an expanded bbox around the source and target vertices to limit the edge count in the routing graph.

Comment: Note that it may be worth to create the bbox (the result of your inner `SELECT`) in a separate step and only pass the actual box geometry into the `edge_sql`!

Comment: @geozelot I created the whole table out of osm2po and then imported it in my database. I created the vertice table now with `pgr_createVerticesTable` command. 
My query now just takes 0.01 seconds! Thank you so much for your help. You are my life saver:D In which regard would it be good to create the bbox in a seperate step? Does this give also more performance?
Can you maybe add an answer that I could mark this post as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I always follow this performance tip and most of the time it solves my slow
https://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html

- Create a bounding box around your source and target vertices to limit the number of roads you are routing - way_vertices_pgr is your osm road topology
- Create index on the geom column and run vacuum analyze
- Tune your database by increase the work_mem if your system allow